# Unable to connect Xamarin MacAgent from VS 2017?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a Xamarin Project. I am trying to connect Xamarin MacAgent from my Windows  - VS 2017 Community Edition to Macbook to test the iPhone Simulator. However, I am not able to connect.

I am connecting from Windows to Macbook using usb-ethernet cable. In the MacBook, System Preferences - I have set the Sharing option - Remote Login - All Users.

My MacBook has Xamarin Studio, XCode Installed on it.

I tested the connection from Windows  - Commmand Prompt by pinging the MacBook IP Address, I get response.  I have turned off firewall on both Macbook and Windows.

In Windows, I have cleaned up the files in the folder : Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch
In MacBook, I have cleaned the cache.

However,  i am still getting the error as " Couln't connect to MyMacbook"

How do i fix  this ??

Comment: Have you check the logs files in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs? What is the reason of not able to connect stated in the log file?

Comment: Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Disconnected from the Mac MyMacBook (169.254.165.159)
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshMessagingConnection|Error|0|An unexpected error occurred with the current SSH Session
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: An established connection was aborted by the server.
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketRead(Int32 length, Byte[] buffer)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.ReceiveMessage()
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.MessageListener()

Comment: MyMacBook (169.254.165.159) is the name of the macbook.. i tried with macbook name and ip adress

Comment: Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Visual Studio couldn't connect to

Comment: Besides able to ping the server. Did you tried whether you are able to ssh into the Mac in command prompt?

Comment: I am able to ping the Mac.  I am getting error : Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException

Comment: Issue was related to Xamarin Workbook version mismatch on both the computers. After upgrading the Xamarin version and make sure that both Mac and Windows has the same version - I am able to connect the MacAgent from Windows - VS 2017. Issue resolved.